# Delete URL history in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, history

I'm looking for a way to delete a whole URL in Google Chrome.

Do I need to run some other program or can it be done in the browser itself?

Comment: ONE url out of manys?

Comment: @Akira - You can do that in Firefox. Just start typing url and press DEL when you select it.

Comment: @Shiki: i know that. i asked the OP what (s)he wants. "whole url" is not really specific. one can delete a single entry ("one whole url") from the history in chrome, as well as the whole history .. and all that without any 3rd party stuff.

Comment: @akira - okay okay sorry.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/273278/how-to-remove-an-entry-from-chromes-remembered-urls for a better answer.

Answer (score 43):

I found the answer from [here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/TVAhznrWabs):

1. Type part of the URL, so it shows up in your suggestions.
2. Use the arrow keys to move to it.
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> (for Mac, press <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>) to remove the link.

Comment: I've only seen `fn` on notebook keyboards, to form substitutes for keys like `PgUp`.  Is it on all Apple keyboards?  (I use a Microsoft Natural.)

Comment: doesn't work anymore on mac

Comment: For what it worths, it still works for me on my Macbook with fn + Shitt + delete. However, even that doesn't seem to work on some particularly links. So you could be right. And unfortunately, I don't know enough to help you further.

Comment: Works for me so far on Mac :)

Comment: Can also confirm that this does *not* work on my Mac Mini.

Comment: Figured it out: I also had the site bookmarked. Delete the bookmark, autocomplete stopped.

Comment: There is a [mouse-click solution](https://superuser.com/a/1824529/282347) (requires no key-combo shortcut).

Answer (score 2):

1. Click the "Tools" menu.
2. Select Options.
3. Click the Under the Hood tab.
4. Click Clear browsing data.
5. Select the "Clear browsing history" checkbox.
6. Use the "Clear data from this period" menu to select the amount of data you want to delete. 7. Select Everything to clear your entire browsing history completely.
7. Click Clear browsing data

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/)

Comment: Not sure why you are recommending a separate tool rather than use the browsers built in method...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove something specifically from your history, open Chrome and go to [chrome://history/#e=1&p=0](http://chrome://history/#e=1&p=0).

You may have to copy and paste that link, it doesn't seem to like to link directly to it.

Answer (score 1):

Browser itself: you can inject JavaScript code like this.

**Step 1**
Since Chrome history is queried inside a iFrame, we have to visit:
**chrome://history-frame/** (copy and paste URL)

**Step 2**
Do the search query.

**Step 3**
Open the Chrome console(<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>) and execute:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
  if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox"){
    inputs[i].checked = true;
  }
}
document.getElementById("remove-selected").disabled = false
document.getElementById("remove-selected").click()
document.getElementById("alertOverlayOk").click()
```

Actually this deletes the elements in the current page, so it's an incomplete solution. But the next page should automatically load, so you can simply run the code again (`Up arrow` then `Return`) until everything is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Open your chrome history tab from the right most corner of your window and remove any particular URL from it or select clear browsing data, a pop up windows appears select all check boxes and  click on clear browsing data tab.

Answer (score 0):

There is a UI-option (no key-combo shortcut needed) just click on the `x` button.

[image]