# How to remove an entry from Chrome's Remembered URLs from the url bar?

Tags: google-chrome

I've got a URL in Chrome "local.mysite.com" that autopopulates when I start typing "local.my" into the URL bar.

*Note that this URL DOES NOT EXIST in my browser history (at chrome://history/#e=1&p=0) because it isn't a real site and therefore couldn't ever be successfully visited and therefore never shows up in my history.*

The URL I *want* is "local.mysite.com/subdir/". That URL is 3 down in the suggested results because I keep accidentally hitting "enter" when it auto-suggests the unwanted first URL thus reinforcing its assumption that that is the one I want.

How do I get rid of the "local.mysite.com" entry in Chrome's memory?

Comment: Here's the same question with an answer: http://superuser.com/questions/160137/delete-url-history-in-google-chrome

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome: remove URL from autocomplete which doesn't show up in history?](http://superuser.com/questions/328515/chrome-remove-url-from-autocomplete-which-doesnt-show-up-in-history)

Comment: This is "practically the canonical" answer relative to those other links, these days :|

Comment: @luchaninov you are correct that that other question you linked to is a duplicate of this one. Note that this question was submitted 4 months before the one you  linked to.

Comment: @cmcculloh this is an even earlier submission of same question (that this duplicates) [Delete URL history in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/160137/delete-url-history-in-google-chrome)

Answer (score 709, accepted):

Follow the steps below to remove individual items from the address bar's remembered URLs:

1. Type `local.mysite.com`
2. Use the <kbd>↑</kbd> <kbd>↓</kbd> keys to move focus to the item you wish to delete
3. Press the relevant keys depending on which OS you are using:

### Windows and Linux:

- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>

### macOS:

- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> (when the keyboard has a dedicated <kbd>Del</kbd> key)
- Press <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> (otherwise)

---

[image: info] **Note**: this will only work for items that have the paper icon ([image: Paper icon]) next to them.

*In older versions of Chrome this is a globe icon ([image: Globe icon]) instead.*

Comment: Note: In newer versions the icon got replaced by a "paper" icon.

Comment: If the there is a 'star' icon, type 'chrome://bookmarks' then search and delete

Comment: Remember you must use the UP/Down Arrow keys to select the remembered URL you wish to delete ### THIS IS CRITICAL ###

Comment: Does this affect Chromes local history?

Comment: On my macbook I have to hit `⌘`+`delete`.

Comment: Sometimes you need to check "Mobile Bookmarks". Open your bookmark manager and try to find those items... ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing out Shift+Fn+Delete on MacBook

Comment: What is the corresponding entry in Chromebook? No delete button there.

Comment: what work to me in Linux and Chrome 61 is pressing Shift + Backspace

Comment: sorry, I meant Ctrl + Shift + Backspace

Comment: I'm on Windows, the page has a "paper" icon by it, and Shift-Delete does nothing.

Comment: seems depreciated: typing `local.mysite.com` in the URL field opens the page `http://local.mysite.com/` (which is a commercial website)

Comment: This does not work on my Mac Mini. I tried both keyboard shortcuts, neither work.

Comment: Figured it out: I also had the site bookmarked. Delete the bookmark, autocomplete stopped.

Comment: in my case, it works with `fn + ctrl + shift +delete ` on macbook pro

Comment: This works in Brave (September 2023 version) as well (on iMac 13.x).

Comment: There is a [mouse-click solution](https://superuser.com/a/1824529/282347) (requires no key-combo shortcut).

Answer (score 22):

Another option is to browse the history tab of Chrome (`chrome://history`) and click the menu next to the URL you want to delete.

Below is a screenshot - sorry it is in German, but you should get the idea. In the German menu it is the second option (*Aus Verlauf entfernen*).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What if you want to delete all "MacRumors" entries?

Comment: @OmarOthman Newer version now have a checkbox next to each entry. The steps would be 1) search the history for the items you want to delete. 2) Click the check box of the first item you'd like to remove. 3) Then check the last item you'd like to remove while holding down the SHIFT key. 4) Use the (also new) button at the top of the list to delete all of the select items.

Comment: Deleting it from the history will not always mean it's deleted from the autocomplete auf the omnibar.

Answer (score 2):

In Chrome v86 (maybe earlier too) on my MacOS when I type in the URL bar and move the mouse cursor over a suggestion, an X **button appears** with the tooltip "Remove suggestion". After clicking this X, the chosen suggestion no longer appears.

[image]

Comment: This only works for entries which are populated from history.

Answer (score 0):

A recent version of Chrome changed how to remove entries from the auto-complete list: you should now use the `X` button on the (far) right of the URL, in the auto-completion list.
That button will only appear for the first suggestion, but will also appear for other suggestions if you hover over them.

Comment: This only works for entries which are populated from history.