# Deleting a specific URL suggestion in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, history

In Firefox, I can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> to delete a single item from the URL history (the URL suggestions).

How can I delete a specific mistyped URL item (only one) from the history in Google Chrome, so it won't show up as a suggestion?

Comment: Thus the invention of the incognito window.

Comment: [*How to remove an entry from Chrome's Remembered URLs from the url bar?*](http://superuser.com/questions/273278/how-to-remove-an-entry-from-chromes-remembered-urls-from-the-url-bar)

Comment: I cannot believe I forgot this shortcut. Was it Command? Ctr? Opt? Combination? Well, I've just found something easier to remember: http://superuser.com/a/676704/35572

Answer (score 131):

To delete a single autosuggested URL, start typing the address as you normally would—Google.com in my example. Then, when the unwanted autocomplete suggestion appears, use your keyboard's arrow keys to highlight the suggestion in the drop-down menu below the address bar.

Finally, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> and poof! The suggestion disappears.

On a Mac, you may have to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Screencast:

[image: How to delete page from Chrome Suggestion]

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. I just tried this on my Mac and it worked. Only difference is I have to press Shift+Fn+Backspace because thats how you press delete on a macbook pro.

I am on Chrome Version  45.0.2454.85.

Comment: Working ok in 2016! Related answer http://superuser.com/questions/273278/how-to-remove-an-entry-from-chromes-remembered-urls-from-the-url-bar

Comment: Mac users: Shift + Fn + Backspace

Comment: For Mac users, this didn't work for me because I was using an external keyboard that already had a dedicated delete key "del" (in place of the power key).  So instead of Shift + Fn + delete/backspace, I had to do Shift + dedicated "del" key.

Comment: Make sure that the mouse cursor is not over any of the suggested rows and you only use the keyboard. Another option is to hover the line with mouse cursor and a "X" button appears at the end of the line *if* Chrome supports removing that suggestion.

Comment: None of the above suggestions worked for me. No `X` buttons ever appearing. No effect with `backspace`, either with `FN` pressed or not. Turned out the page was bookmarked (wrongly; as 99% of my bookmarks) and **I needed to first remove the bookmark** ⭐️, in order to have the shortcut work (or the `X` button appear).

Comment: This does not work for me in Chrome 98 in Windows. Nothing from above works

Comment: Just to add more confusion, on my Macbook Pro with a Magic Keyboard with Numeric Keypad it's `cmd + shift + delete`

Comment: You can't delete if it is also bookmarked.  DELETE any bookmarks FIRST.. then you can use this technique.

Answer (score 21):

It works the same way in Chrome.

[image]

But, basically, only the items with the globe in front can be deleted.

If you're now going "*Yeah, I know that, I want to remove the history items which I can remove just fine from the history by using `chrome://history/`, but from the address bar!* " then [you seem to be out of luck](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=5be002aeda9f7fd9&hl=en).

Comment: What about the items with the clock icon?

Comment: What if it does have a file icon on it. How do I remove it? Is very annoygin https://www.dropbox.com/s/d08iomuhx5q587x/Screenshot%202015-02-11%2009.58.01.png?dl=0 -- Clearly * Modifier+Delete does not work on OS X 10.10.

Comment: @sorin it does, but on OS X delete = fn + backspace, so to delete an url you have to push: Shift + fn + Backspace

Comment: @takeshin Items with the Star icon can be removed or edited in the Bookmark Manager. This was useful to me because I bookmarked the wrong URL and would be annoyed when I'd select the bookmark and the non-existent page would load

Answer (score 6):

For Chrome URL suggestions that you seem to be unable to clear with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> or in Chrome's settings, navigate to this directory:

Windows

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

Mac

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default
```

Linux

```
~/.config/google-chrome/Default
```

Remove the `History` and `Web Data` files. Removing only the `History` file seems like it works at first, but for me the URLs always come back. After removing both files, these unwanted URL suggestions have never come back for me.

Comment: +1 for the `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` folder location, however, for me the mistyped URL suggestions are stored in: `Shortcuts` and `Shortcuts-journal`

Answer (score 6):

I see that in Chrome v86 (may be elier too; MacOs) when you type letters on url bar and move mouse on suggestion then "x" **button appear** for "Remove Suggestion"

[image]

Comment: This was the only way that worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If all other answers to this question fail to solve the problem:

Bookmarked urls also show up in the suggestion box. So if at some point you added a bookmark to a page that is no longer relevant and you don't want it to show up as suggestion, then you should also remove it from your bookmarks.

You can do this by navigating to chrome://bookmarks, and searching for the url that you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for @Ian's answer locating the folder - but actually removing files `Shortcuts` and `Shortcuts-journal` worked for me: all mistyped-URLs suggestions are now removed.

To investigate which files in this folder were storing the suggestions, I installed the MobaXTerm Unix-like shell tool for windows, and went to `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` and did a `grep url *` where I typed the actual URL in place of `url`  suggestion e.g. `grep facebook.cm *` - the `grep` showed where Chrome was storing the suggestion - in Shortcut and Shortcut-journal

(I used MobaXterm to be able to use `grep` on Windows - Windows search does not find everything)

But, of course, you shouldn't need to install MobaXTerm- this was used to help my investigation to find where the incorrect URLs were stored. So...

**All you need to know to delete ALL mistyped URL suggestions in Chrome on Windows 7 is:**

To remove mis-typed URL suggestions in Chrome, go to: `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` and remove files `Shortcuts` and `Shortcuts-journal`

(As a footnote, I think it is bad that Chrome's clear browsing history: `chrome://chrome/settings/clearBrowserData` and `chrome://chrome/settings/cookies` do not remove mis-typed incorrect URLs as suggestions.)

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Google Chrome extension that can help you do that same

[Click&Clean](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickclean/ghgabhipcejejjmhhchfonmamedcbeod?hl=en)

After installing the extension, click the button in your browser toolbar, hover your mouse over 'Clear private data' and click the settings icon.

In the Chrome section, you can click the trash can icon next to any data type to remove it immediately, but you can also configure Click&Clean for faster use in future. Tick the boxes next to anything you would like to be able to quickly and easily delete from your browsing history, and click the 'Run cleaner' button to remove them.

If you want to tailor the time frame for deletion, use the 'Obliterate' drop-down menu to choose choose how far back you would like to wipe. In future, you can simply click the Click&Clean button in the Chrome toolbar and then click 'Clear private data' to wipe out everything you have selection in one fell swoop.

Check the screenshot below

[image: click and clean]