# How to remove Google Reader URLs from Google Chrome address bar?

Tags: google-chrome, history, autocomplete

How can I remove Google Reader URLs from my Chrome omnibox?

[image]

Usually <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> works, but it doesn't appear to work here.

Comment: Check this: [**Deleting a specific URL suggestion in Chrome**](http://superuser.com/a/476607/138020)

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in latest version Chrome 23.0.1271.64. Thanks Google :)

Comment: Can I suggest marking your answer as the solution?