# How to make Google Chrome forget a website

Tags: google-chrome, history, cookies

Whenever I visit a certain a website, Google chrome somehow still has the exact input I typed in to perform a search. Every time I go back to the website, it automatically executes that same original search over again.

How do I make Google Chrome forget that I was ever there, and give me a fresh page each time I go to it?

Comment: you could try visiting in Incognito Mode

Comment: Uninstall Chrome. Download Firefox. Go to history, type your website's address, right click and choose "forget this site" :) - Yep, this is not available in Chrome!

Comment: @MarioAwad It is possible thru the history page of chrome and chromium as well.

Comment: @guido you're right thanks for the answer and I think yours is a better answer to the question. Upvoting :)

Comment: @MarioAwad yours is the best answer. chrome is so anti-user it's not even funny.

Comment: @MarioAwad Chrome only allows to forget an item at a time but not a website AFAIK. Upvoting your comment as per OP's question title. PS try that on a ChromeOS device #-|

Comment: This is helpful to not have the URL appearning in the autosuggest in the Chrome's url bar: https://superuser.com/q/398385/169199

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is how usually I do this:

- Open Chrome History <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.
- In the searchbox, top-right, type some keyword to identify the urls you want to delete; chrome will match the input against the url and the title of webpages in history.
- Double-check that you got only what you really want to delete.
- Select the checkbox left of the first result, then scroll down and check the latest checkbox *while* pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>. This will select everything (that was filtered with keywords above). Alternatively, just select what you want.
- Click the remove selected button.

Comment: You sire, are awesome. Thank you for this - was getting annoyed finding 'use firefox herp derp' answers and the like.

Comment: It appears that ctrl-A also works for select all

Comment: This procedure is terrible pedestrian and will be such a pain in the neck if the site you want to delete include hundred of sub-pages. People at Google: was so difficult to include a context menu item labeled "Forget this site"? One of many reasons why I run away from Chrome when I have the choice.

Comment: warning, this will not make chrome forget cached http 301 moved permanent links, even if you delete all pages related to that domain.

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1166181/967119 to clear 301 moved permanently Chrome cache.

Comment: 8 years later, and this is *still* nowhere near as good as Firefox's ctl-shift-h. It doesn't forget `Strict-Transport-Security`, for example, and continues to force `http` to `https`. It also doesn't re-check a security certificate. It just rather dumbly tells you that a site is insecure, even though the details show that it has a valid certificate. It doesn't fix the security problem until you restart it. Firefox gets all this right.

Answer (score 4):

More precise in the urlbar (like [shown here](https://superuser.com/questions/328515/chrome-remove-url-from-autocomplete-which-doesnt-show-up-in-history)):

- Mark all the text in the urlbar of the unpopular history entry using <kbd>End</kbd> and then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Pos1</kbd>
- Then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>

Tada!

If you work in the history and you have the extension Better History -> "Clear all from this site". This is pretty fast, if you have a lot of visits on the site.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. It doesn't quite answer the original question, but it's a much simpler way to do what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: This, this, a thousand times this. On a Macbook you would do `Fn+Shift+Backspace`

Answer (score 0):

Use the *Forget about this site* browser extension from Blaise Kal for Chrome based browsers and Firefox:

- Homepage https://github.com/blaise-io/forget-about-this-site#readme
- [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/forget-about-this-site/okiohagmnigihpbleoloddfldckiknea/)
- [Firefox Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/forget-about-this-site/)

Answer (score 0):

For deleting a specific site from you history:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>

type: **host:*{site url like youtube.com}***

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>

<kbd>del</kbd> / delete button

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].

Answer (score -4):

You can clear your cache and cookies--maybe even clear your saved auto fill form data.  In Chrome, do the following:

1. Go to Tools > Clear Browsing Data...
2. Under *Obliterate the following items from*:, change it to *The
   beginning of time*
3. Place a check mark next to *Empty the cache*
4. Place a check mark next to *Delete cookies and other site plugin
   data*
5. Place a check mark next to *Clear saved Autofill form data*
6. Click *Clear browsing data*
7. Refresh the browser or revisit the page

This should make Chrome forget you were ever there.

Comment: That'll kill everything for every site, no? Isn't there a way to do a more surgically precise removal of the data just for that site?

Comment: Yes I found it. YOU can simply click "Clear Browsing HIstory" and you can select from when (i.e. the past hour)

Comment: This will clear stuff for all websites and not for a single selected website.