# Google Chrome: Delete All URLs for Website in Address bar

Tags: google-chrome, browser, internet, history

How do I delete all Chrome suggestions for a particular website hostname? eg [www.amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com)   or [www.food.com](http://www.food.com) .

This answer
[Deleting a specific URL suggestion in Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/398385/deleting-a-specific-url-suggestion-in-chrome) gives specific url, but it still leaves different various branch autofill urls under one website host .

Example if I delete Amazon Books chrome history, it still leaves another website for amazon electronics  ( http://www.amazon.com/books  ,  http://www.amazon.com/electronics )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address bar suggestions are linked to your history (I just tested this).

Hence, the easiest way to remove suggestions for a particular host is to clear the visits from your history:

> - Open Chrome History <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.
> - In the searchbox, top-right, type some keyword to identify the urls you want to delete; chrome will match the input against the url and the title of webpages in history.
> - Double-check that you got only what you really want to delete.
> - Select the checkbox left of the first result, then scroll down and check the latest checkbox *while* pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>. This will select everything (that was filtered with keywords above). Alternatively, just select what you want.
> - Click the remove selected button.

[Source](https://superuser.com/a/768687/291509)

---

Otherwise consider using an extension such as ["Forget about this site"](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/forget-about-this-site/okiohagmnigihpbleoloddfldckiknea).