# How can I delete all web history that matches a specific query in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

In Google Chrome, is it possible to delete all search history that matches a specific query (for example, en.wikipedia.org)?

Comment: It is possible to select all items in a search from Google Web History. I wonder if it's possible to synchronize Google Web History with Chrome's web history.

Comment: There's an extension called "Updater for Google Web History" - it appears that this extension allows Google Web History to work in Google Chrome.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Could you please update the accepted answer to http://superuser.com/a/791728/84229 from `Fabricio PH`. That's the original correct answer. The currently accepted one had simply copied the right answer without attributing any credit. Now it has been reverted back to its original version.

Comment: @AndersonGreen You should choose [Pooya](http://superuser.com/questions/480646/how-can-i-delete-all-web-history-that-matches-a-specific-query-in-google-chrome/723264#723264)'s as the correct answer, it's the simplest, fastest way to do it. Plus, Fabricio's doing some self advertising on his answer, which isn't complete.

Comment: To make it quick: search and then hit "ctrl + a" to select all results

Answer (score 104, accepted):

**Update Jan 2019**

Now Chrome supports the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

---

**Original answer**

You can take the hacker shortcut **injecting JavaScript code**.

**Step 1**
Since Chrome history is queried inside a iFrame, we have to visit:
**chrome://history-frame/** (copy and paste URL)

**Step 2**
Do the search query.

**Step 3**
Open the Chrome console(<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>) and execute:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
  if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox"){
    inputs[i].checked = true;
  }
}
document.getElementById("remove-selected").disabled = false
```

**Step 4**
Hit the '*Remove selected items*' button.

Actually this deletes the elements in the current page. I might try to extend it, but it's a good starting point.

Comment: This is not working anymore. document.getElementsByTagName('input') is returning empty array.

Comment: @FabricioPH I ran the script in chrome://history instead of "chrome://history-frame, which is why it didn't work for me. It works well inside the frame.

Comment: This is great! At first I ran it in a different tab, which didn't work (in hindsight, for logically attainable reasons.) So I reopend the Console in the same tab as chrome://history-frame, and it all worked.

Comment: very clean and easy solution

Comment: It says `xxxxx:x Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'disabled' of null
    at <anonymous>:x:xxx`

Comment: This solution is outdated: simply hit "ctrl + a"

Comment: @wuppi You just saved me this should be the correct answer

Comment: The correct answer is "scroll to the bottom, then hit CTRL-A, then delete"

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Thank you! It seems like an oversight that Ctrl+A won’t *actually* select all, it just selects all items *currently* loaded into the view…

Answer (score 151):

That’s simple & easy.

Search for what you want to remove. Select the first one. Now scroll to the latest result. Press <kbd>shift</kbd> & choose the latest one. Now all matches are selected and you can remove them together.

---

In some cases, removing an address from history results is not enough for stoping that address from appearing in url bar auto suggestions.

In that case visit here : https://superuser.com/a/273280/121184

Comment: Further information is here: http://superuser.com/a/747816/85129

Comment: Or you can take a hacker shortcut, see my answer below ;)

Comment: @AndersonGreen This is the correct answer, not Fabricio's.

Comment: This one is not obvious. I expect the text to get selected.

Comment: @AdriánSalgado Meh, too much scrolling :P

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: "ctrl + a" does select all visible elements

Comment: Hmmm Great @wuppi didn't know about that. btw it is fn + Command in mac.
you can add your comment as an answer and i'd link to it or if you dont want to do so i can update my answer

Comment: one of the answers further down covers that too (found that out after placing my comment)

Answer (score 20):

## For *literal* values of "query"...

You can even query your Chrome history using SQL. (*Firefox too: see below. Of course, the appropriate file path will have to be changed*).

First of all, you need to locate the Chrome History file. This is, on my system, in

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Leonardo Serni\Impostazioni locali\Dati applicazioni\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

which ought to translate in a more general

```
<USER FOLDER>\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

In there, you will find a "History" file. It is a SQLite3 file, **and to manipulate it, Chrome has to be closed**. If you make a mess of it, delete the History file and start anew - it's just as if you had cleared the whole Chrome history.

Then, rename the file to `History.sqlite3` and install [SQLiteMan](http://sqliteman.com/) (or any other SQLite3 editor - in Windows, double-clicking on the file *might* be enough to trigger a suggestion), then open the file (*n.b. some utilities might not need the renaming thing. Maybe try without renaming first, to save work*).

In the URLS table, you will find the URLs you have visited. For example I can run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM urls WHERE url LIKE '%meetup%';
```

to view all occurrences of 'meetup' in either the host or pathname part of the URLs I visited. Or I could search for *pr0n*, or... **anything at all, as long as I adhere to SQL syntax**.

You can even use the other information to run the query, for example the time of last visit. Only remember that you need to convert the dates to **Chrome time**, which is the number of microseconds elapsed from **January 1st, year of our Lord 1601**. On a Unix box, typing `date +%s` will tell you the number of seconds; multiply by one million, add 11644473600 and you're done.

For example, select visits after October 1st, 2013:

```
SELECT * FROM urls WHERE ((last_visit_time/1000000)-11644473600) - 
    strftime('%s', '2013-10-01 00:00:00') > 0;
```

To delete, just replace `SELECT *` with `DELETE` and press F9 to execute the query.

You can use `NOW()` instead of the current date, and any other [SQLite syntax](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html).

(In case, the "Archive History" file holds the last history archived by Chrome).

When you're done, if needed, rename back the file to "History".

## Automating it: one-click sanitization

You need a command-line SQLite utility such as `sqlite3` or `sql3tool`. Then you write a script or batch file, modifying the code below with the appropriate paths (you don't want to clear **my** history leaving yours untouched, do you?):

```
# ENSURE CHROME IS CLOSED (pskill by SysInternals might be useful)
echo "DELETE * FROM urls WHERE url LIKE '%facebook%' OR url LIKE '%twitter%';" | sql3tool "C:\Documents and Settings\Leonardo Serni\Impostazioni locali\Dati applicazioni\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History"
echo "DELETE * FROM urls WHERE url LIKE '%porn%' OR url LIKE '%my-employer-is-a-moron%';" | sql3tool "C:\Documents and Settings\Leonardo Serni\Impostazioni locali\Dati applicazioni\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History"
echo "DELETE * FROM urls WHERE url LIKE ..."
```

Only remember that this erases *your* history on *your* instance of Chrome. If, for example, you use a proxy, and that proxy keeps logs, **all those URLs will be still available in the logs**.

**UPDATE**: Also, if you're using some brain-dead SQL tool that requires the file to have an explicit and known extension, you will have to perform an appropriate RENAME before starting operations, and another to put things back in order when you've finished:

```
REN "C:\Documents and Settings\Leonardo Serni\Impostazioni locali\Dati applicazioni\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History" "C:\Documents and Settings\Leonardo Serni\Impostazioni locali\Dati applicazioni\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History.sqlite3"
echo "DELETE * FROM urls WHERE url LIKE '%facebook%' OR url LIKE '%twitter%';" | sql3tool "C:\Documents and Settings\Leonardo Serni\Impostazioni locali\Dati applicazioni\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History.sqlite3"
REN "C:\Documents and Settings\Leonardo Serni\Impostazioni locali\Dati applicazioni\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History.sqlite3" "C:\Documents and Settings\Leonardo Serni\Impostazioni locali\Dati applicazioni\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History"
```

Anyway, once this is done, **doubleclick on the script icon and hey presto!, your Chrome history is sanitized**. It works with Firefox too; its timestamps might be in some other time reference frame, though (possibly plain Unix), so check the water before jumping in.

## How about cleaning cookies?

You might want to do the same thing to cookies instead of History.

But you'll have noticed, in the Chrome data directory, other files than History, *one of which is named Cookies*... :-)

## Advanced track covering

The SQL trick above is not limited to deletions. You can modify entries with the `UPDATE` command; and after deleting *unneeded* entries, you can use `INSERT` with the appropriate time and date macros to have Chrome believe that you visited some URLs you did not actually visit, or did not visit at some time and date.

This may come in handy in those cases when sanitizing a browser session would result in an unlikely picture of someone staring glazedly at an empty browser window for a very long time, and some kind of idle navigation is preferable. Of course, this assumes that no one notices that each day [there is exactly the same navigation 'template'](https://www.petsymposium.org/2012/papers/hotpets12-4-johnny.pdf).

Comment: The command would be "DELETE from URL ..."

Comment: This is the right answer to the general question! The other answers implicitely assume you have a couple of hundred results at max. I wanted to delete a few hundred pages worth of urls according to patterns and this is the only viable answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14):

You can either visit chrome://history or chrome://history-frame.
On the page you can start searching and when all results are listed simply hit `CTRL + A` to select all visible items. Pressing it again deselects all items.

With the selected items simply delete them via `DEL` key.

Comment: OMG!! I have been a lot of time searching how to do this, since there is not a "select all" option in chrome history. Thanks!!

Comment: @AdrianaHernández welcome, happy to help :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was manually selecting all the entries and didn't know I can use the `CMD + A`

Answer (score 5):

By holding shift and clicking at the first url checkbox and then scrolling down to the last one. This tells google to select all posts in between. You then hit "delete" and Voila history gone for that specific URL

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser Meron. While this may be valid, it duplicates information posted in at least two other answers.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Fabricio PH's awnser, this should be clear all pages of results for a given search on the [chrome://history-frame](http://chrome://history-frame) page when pasted into the devtools console:

```js
var clearHistoryPage, historyInterval;

historyInterval = null;

clearHistoryPage = function() {
  var i, input, inputs, len, spinner;

  // If spinner is visible a new page is still loading
  spinner = document.getElementById('loading-spinner');
  if (!spinner.hasAttribute('hidden')) {
    console.log("Waiting on load");
    return;
  }

  inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  // When no history is present 5 inputs are still present on the history frame page
  if (inputs.length <= 5) {
    console.log("Found 5 or less inputs, stopping");
    clearInterval(historyInterval);
    return;
  }

  console.log("FOUND " + inputs.length + " results, clearing");
  for (i = 0, len = inputs.length; i < len; i++) {
    input = inputs[i];
    if (input.type === 'checkbox') {
      input.checked = true;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById('remove-selected').disabled = false;
  document.getElementById('remove-selected').click();
  document.getElementById('alertOverlayOk').click();
};

historyInterval = window.setInterval(clearHistoryPage, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, that is currently not supported by Chrome itself.

Though, extensions can request access to your history data. So it would be possible for an extension to fulfill your needs. I do not know of such an extension myself, but a small search, made me find this one:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gjieilkfnnjoihjjonajndjldjoagffm

Possibly that extension can do what you request.

Comment: This answer is outdated - see [this one](http://superuser.com/a/723264/231678) or [this one](http://superuser.com/a/747816/231678)

Comment: I cannot delete it either, sorry

Comment: That's fine - I'm just pointing it out for future viewers.

Comment: The sad thing is that I lose rep for this :p

Comment: No extension needed, check my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use Chrome with the url : chrome://history/#e=1&p=0

You may have to copy/paste it into your url bar.

Answer (score 1):

In the Chrome bar try searching for the history item you want deleted. Once it appears in the results, scroll down to it using arrow keys (even if it is the first item in the list) and press Shift + Delete.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on the first checkbox.
2. Scroll down to bottom of page.
3. Hold shift and click on the last checkbox.
4. All checkbox will be selected; Scroll to top, where "Remove Selected Items" button is present.
5. Click on button. Selected items will be deleted :)

Comment: Welcome to super user. I would suggest that questions like these are not the best to answer! Other answers already have the options on how to do this including your method.

Answer (score 1):

If you come across this topic from google, there is an easier way to delete multiple items now.

- Go on https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity?product=6
- Search for something
- Click on the 3 dots menu in the search box
- Click on "Delete all"
- ???
- Profit

Comment: this method doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

```
// Tested on Chrome Version 72.0.3626.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)
// 1) Open Chrome browser history.
// 2) Search for specific history you want to delete.
// 3) Cut-and-paste the code below in the Chrome Browser console.
// Enjoy!

(function (){
let historyApp = document.getElementById("history-app");
historyApp.items[0].selectAllItems();

// Delete history with a popup confirmation prompt
historyApp.deleteSelected();

// Delete with no prompt
// historyApp.items[0].deleteSelected_()  

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Type the url you want to remove in the history tab as in the screenshot below, toggle the developer console(mac: opt+cms+i) and select the `<iron-list` element. Then toggle the js console(esc), and type the following code in the console:

```
$0.querySelectorAll('history-item').forEach(_ => _.root.querySelectorAll('cr-checkbox').forEach(_ => _.click()))
```

It should select all the visible elements. Click on delete, and repeat until the list is empty or chrome gives a strange error.

[image: history tab]

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension in Google Chrome:
[History Calendar](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-calendar/ilfjhacjjbcdmimjeaakpnlhdcloijcg?hl=en)

Its exactly what I was searching for... it makes history deleting etc just like firefox i.e. fast and smooth. If you have over 2000 history marks for sites like amazon.com, google chrome history viewer will take ages (go page by page), but in firefox history window (or using the above mentioned chrome extn), you can select all 2000 and delete in one go

Comment: It shows 404 on that link

Answer (score 0):

- open  `chrome:history` and search for the website(s) that you want to delete.
- open your chrome console with `ctrl-shift-j`.
- if applicable, ensure that the dropdown right above the console reads `history (history-frame)` and not `top,` etc.
- run the following code in the console:

`$$('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(el => el.checked = true);
 $("remove-selected").disabled = false;`

Answer (score 0):

If Fabricio's code doesn't work for you I found that this code is working and additionally clicking the "remove selected" button for me so the only thing i have to do is to click confirmation dialog.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.entry-box input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(function(input) {
  input.checked = true;
});

document.getElementById("remove-selected").disabled = false
document.getElementById("remove-selected").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
function hasText(a){
    if(a.innerText){
        return true}
    else{
        return false}
}

function isCheckbox(element){
    if(element.type=='checkbox'){
        return true
    }
}

function removeItemsofQuery(query){
    var element=document.getElementsByClassName('entry-box')
    var checkbox=[]
    var titles=[]
    for(i=0; i<element.length; i++){
        var children=element[i].children
        for(j=0; j<children.length; j++){
            if(hasText(element[i].children[j])==true && element[i].children[j].className!="time" ){
                var ds=element[i].children[j].innerText
                titles.push(ds)
            }
            if (isCheckbox(element[i].children[j])==true){
                var hg=element[i].children[j]
                checkbox.push(hg)
            }
        }
        }

    for(g=0; g<element.length; g++){
        var queries=titles[g].indexOf(query)
        if(queries>0){
            checkbox[g].checked=true
        }
    }
    var RS=document.getElementById('remove-selected')
    RS.disabled=false
    RS.click()
}
```

Put it into the chrome browser console one the history **FRAME** page. Not regular history, but the history **FRAME**. Then, call the function `removeItemsofQuery`, and input the term you want to search for and remove as the argument. Press enter, and press the final remove button. Then, you're done. Congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

Start writing the term that you want to search for, when the unwanted term appears use the up and down arrow to go to that term and press Shift + Delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
async function selectAll() {
    var count = 0;
    var inputs = document.getElementById("history-app").shadowRoot.getElementById("history").shadowRoot.getElementById("infinite-list").children;

    for (var i = 1; i < inputs.length; ++i) {

        if (inputs[i].shadowRoot.getElementById("checkbox").getAttribute('aria-checked') == "false") {
            inputs[i].shadowRoot.getElementById("checkbox").click();
            count++;
            await sleep(20);
        }
    }
    if (c > 0) selectAll()
}
selectAll()
```

Comment: Please explain (in English *words*) how this answers the question.

Comment: Go to  chrome://history , search what you want, open Chrome Console, copy & paste the code above to select all