# How can I easily delete many items at once from the Chrome history?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to remove a large number of specific items from the Chrome history.

I can search for my term, but then I have to click a lot of checkboxes just to remove every item. Is there a way to make this process faster?

Comment: Open the sqlite database `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History` with your favorite sqlite database browser while Chrome isn't running.  Use SQL queries to remove records.

Comment: @Zoredache You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can also <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> to select multiple items in history and remove them at once.

This works as of Chrome version 33, and possibly earlier versions.

1. Perform a search to bring up the relevant history items
2. Click the first result
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> the last result
4. Click Remove Selected Items

Answer (score 9):

1. Perform a search to bring up the items you want to remove the history.

   [image]
2. Open the Chrome Developer Tools console by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.
3. Make sure to select the **history-frame** frame as the target frame for the console.

   [image]
4. Execute the following snippet in the console (by pasting it and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>) to mark all checkboxes in the history.

   ```
   var checkboxes = $$( "input[type='checkbox']" );
   for( var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; ++i ) {
     checkboxes[ i ].checked = true;
   }
   ```

   Don't forget to double-check the selection and uncheck items which you don't actually want to remove!
5. Clear the selected items from your history by pressing the **Remove selected items**.

   [image]

Comment: You should accept your own answer, it's better :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's something I wrote in JavaScript.. It works through the Console Debugger.. I tried using it in a bookmark but I get no response from the page..

** **// UPDATE (07.28.15)**
I added a shorter approach provided by @Denis Gorbachev to the checkbox targeting, which helped shorten some of this code. I also added "*auto-stop*" functionality, meaning the loop will stop once it has finally cleared the list.

** **// UPDATE (08.20.14)**
I made a few changes to the code, to make it more user friendly. Other users may not be code-savvy, and others may simply prefer convenience. Therefore, I whipped up a couple buttons (start/stop) to control the usage; as well as address some "ASSERTION FAILED" exceptions/errors that were being thrown when attempted to run the script loop.. Enjoy!!

---

**Step 1)** In your address bar, type in the following address to to the meat of the history page.. It's normally loaded in an iframe, with the left-side menu loaded in another frame..

```
chrome://history-frame/
```

**Step 2)** Load your Console Debugger/Viewer by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>
(For Mac users, <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>)
                *Note: You can also press* <kbd>F12</kbd> *and select the "**Console**" tab.*

**Step 3)** In the **Console Debugger/Viewer**, copy & paste the following code:

```
function removeItems() {
removeButton = document.getElementById('remove-selected');
overlayWindow = document.getElementById('overlay');
    //revision (07.28.15): Replaced the For Loop targeting the checkboxes, thanks to Denis Gorbachev via comments (02.19.15)
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]"), function(node) {node.checked = "checked"});
setTimeout(function () {
    if (removeButton.getAttribute("disabled") !== null) {
        removeButton.removeAttribute("disabled")
    }
    /* revision (08.20.14): no longer binding to that condition, button should no longer be disabled, so click! */
    if ((overlayWindow.hasAttribute("hidden")) && (overlayWindow.getAttribute("hidden") !== false)) {
        removeButton.click();
    }
    /* revision (08.20.14): new Interval, to check against the overlay DIV containing the confirmation "Remove" button */
    /* Attempting to click the button while the DIV's "hidden" attribute is in effect will cause FAILED ASSERTION */
    stopButton = setInterval(function () {
        if (overlayWindow.hasAttribute("hidden")) {
            if (overlayWindow.getAttribute("hidden") == "false") {
                hidden = false
            } else {
                hidden = true
            }
        } else {
            hidden = false
        }
        if (!hidden) {
            document.getElementById("alertOverlayOk").click();
            clearInterval(stopButton)
        }
    }, 250)
}, 250)
}
//revision (08.20.14): Lets build our buttons to control this so we no longer need the console
//stop button (08.20.14)
var stopButton = document.createElement('button');
stopButton.setAttribute('id', "stopButton");
stopButton.innerHTML = "Stop";
stopButton.style.background = "#800";
stopButton.style.color = "#fff";
stopButton.style.display = "none";
stopButton.onclick = function () {
    clearInterval(window.clearAllFiltered);
    document.getElementById("stopButton").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("startButton").style.display = ""
};
//start button (08.20.14)
var startButton = document.createElement('button');
startButton.setAttribute('id', "startButton");
startButton.innerHTML = "Start";
startButton.style.background = "#090";
startButton.style.color = "#fff";
startButton.onclick = function () {
    window.clearAllFiltered = setInterval(function () {
/* revision (07.28.15): Stop the Loop automatically if there are no more items to remove */
        if(document.getElementById("results-header").innerText=="No search results found."){
            document.getElementById("stopButton").click();
            }
        if (document.getElementById("loading-spinner").getAttribute("hidden") !== null) {
            removeItems()
        }
    }, 250); //adjust Time Here (1500 [millisec] = 1.5sec)
    document.getElementById("stopButton").style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("startButton").style.display = "none"
};
/* revision (08.20.14): Now we add our buttons, and we're ready to go! */
editingControls = document.getElementById('editing-controls');
editingControls.appendChild(stopButton);
editingControls.appendChild(startButton);
```

This removeItems function will select loop through all form inputs and check all checkboxes, enable the "Remove Selected Items" button and click it. After a half-second, it'll check if the "Are You Sure" prompt is displayed and, if so, click the "Yes/Remove" button automatically for you so that it will load a new list of items to do this process all over again..

The item is looped using the variable "clearAllFiltered", which is a setInterval loop, which is checking for the status of the "Loading" screen..

To start erasing your filtered history items, you can now click the green <kbd>**Start**</kbd> button.

** **// UPDATE (07.28.2015) It will now stop on ITS OWN.**

To stop the loop *manually*, you can now click the red <kbd>**Stop**</kbd> button. Simple as that!

Comment: I actually just posted an update I wrote for it back last August, if you wanted to try the new code out

Comment: The new code doesn't seem to work. I click the start button and the modal window pops up, but before I have a chance to click it, it flashes again with a reload. Nothing gets deleted.

Comment: Thanks for bringing that to my attention @junto

I just updated it again, cleaned up some of the text also to clear some confusion

Comment: Works brilliantly :)

Answer (score 1):

You can take the hacker shortcut **injecting JavaScript code**.

**Step 1**
Since Chrome history is queried inside a iFrame, we have to visit:
**chrome://history-frame/** (copy and paste URL)

**Step 2**
Do the search query.

**Step 3**
Open the Chrome console(<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>) and execute:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
  if (inputs[i].type == "checkbox"){
    inputs[i].checked = true;
  }
}
document.getElementById("remove-selected").disabled = false
```

**Step 4**
Hit the '*Remove selected items*' button.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg actually if you look carefully is necessary to enable the remove-selected button. Nobody was doing that in the previous answers.