# Clearing old browsing data in Chrome instead of newer data

Tags: google-chrome, browser, browser-addons, history

Currently you can clear browsing data from now up to one day/week/month etc.

Is there a way to do the opposite and clear everything older than one day/week/month?

Comment: Take a look at [eHistory](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ehistory/hiiknjobjfknoghbeelhfilaaikffopb) extension. You can clear history using a custom date range.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that the Chrome developers only catered to adolescents  needing to hide browsing history from their parents. Us older people
need therefore to use third-party software, or use a database browser to attack
directly the history database.

Here are a couple of add-ons that might help.
They are not recent, and I do not know if they still work :

- [eHistory - Enhanced History](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ehistory/hiiknjobjfknoghbeelhfilaaikffopb) (last updated February 15, 2014)
- [History Limiter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/history-limiter/dpdjaigdefdamkfcgjhbmpjbhiejjkph) (last updated June 8, 2011 !)

In the Do It Yourself way, see the thread
[How can I delete all web history that matches a specific query in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/480646/how-can-i-delete-all-web-history-that-matches-a-specific-query-in-google-chrome),
where two solutions are proposed :

1. Hacking the Chrome history page itself, `chrome://history-frame/`,
   by JavaScript injection,
   although the described solution deletes all history, so still
   needs to be improved to work in a selective manner.
2. Using an SQL viewer to manipulate directly the Chrome History database,
   normally found under Windows as the file
   `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History`,
   as is detailed in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/653877/8672).
   I suspect that this approach is probably the most likely to work.

Comment: [Clear History \[Advance Fork\] extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clear-history-advance-for/kihobnjokffgdfnhjdfiaibalbgfolic)

Comment: The two mentioned extensions are no longer available. @Totor mentioned a third extension, but it seems it can only keep the last 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to chrome://history/older and [Make sure 'Older' is selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MHFH.png). Then you can press F12 to go to developer tools, find "Console" tab and paste and run this code (and wait a while):

```
var fun = ()=>{setTimeout(() => {document.querySelectorAll('button[title=Delete]').forEach(b => b.click()); console.log('d'); fun();}, 1); }; fun();
```

It clicks the "Delete" button for each item on the list.