# Selectively clear Firefox histroy

Tags: firefox, history

I have the following two cases:

1. When I use some browser extension, Firefox adds the extension's window to the URL history - even if I am browsing in a private window. This can be seen in the screenshot below.
2. Sometimes I forgot to switch to a private window and a "confidential" URL is stored in the browser history.

**Question:**

Is it possible to **selectively** clear the Firefox history, so I can remove the affected entries but keep all other entries in the history?

Example: Specifying some pattern like "`moz-extension://*`" or "`*://confidential.example.com/*`" and only clear all entries matching the pattern from the history.

Because more than 700 entries are affected, manually selecting all entries is not practicable.

I'm thinking about accessing the file "`places.sqlite`" using some small program to perform this task; however, I don't like to do this if there is already a built-in solution for this.

(If the OS matters: I'm using Ubuntu Linux 18.04.)

---

Screenshot showing a browser extension window in the browser history:

[image: Browser extension windows in the history]

Comment: Have you tried [Delete Browsing History Of Domain Of Current Page – Get this Extension for  Firefox (en-US)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/delete-history-of-domain/)?

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you very much. This would help me with the "confidential" URL; however my main problem are the URLs of extensions and I don't know if that extension is capable of handling this.

Comment: There is also [Delete History – Get this Extension for  Firefox (en-US)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/delete-history/?utm_source=addons.mozilla.org&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=search) whcih hasa delete list configuration.

Comment: This answer [How can I delete all web history that matches a specific query in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/a/653877/337631) also works for Firefox, using [sqliteman: sqlite3 admin and devel tool download | SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sqliteman/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the *History* sidebar.
- Right-click on one of the entries you want to remove to open a context menu.
- Click on "*Forget about this site*" to remove **all** history entries for this domain.

Comment: Indeed, this solution also works for extension's URLs (`moz-extension://...`). Thanks a lot!