# Modify entries in browser url autocomplete bar

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, autocomplete

Recently a website I often visit changed its domain name. As a result, all of my browser's URL autocomplete entries are incorrect. They point to `example.com` instead of `example2.com`.

I'm interested in fixing this on Firefox and Chrome.

I know I can delete entries like so: https://superuser.com/a/273280/70097, but is there a way to rename all the `example.com` entries to `example2.com`? I would rather preserve all my useful autocomplete entries without having to start from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Main sources for *URL* autocomplete of *Firefox Awesome Bar* and *Google Chrome address bar* are both `Sqlite` databases, stored in user profile folders of browsers, e.g. in Windows XP respectively somewhere under (roughly)

```
"%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\"
```

and

```
"%USERPROFILE%\Local Settings\AppData\Google\Chrome\User Data\"
```

Firefox database: file `places.sqlite`, table `moz_places`, field `url`

Google Chrome database: file `Favicons`, table `favicons`, field `url`

Data could be managed and edited by simple yet powerful tool [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)...

Comment: Thanks, I got it working in Firefox, however the Chrome solution doesn't seem to work. I still have the wrong entries in autocomplete

Comment: 1. Did you empty the Chrome cache? 2. I didn't say database `Favicons` is the _only_ autocomplete source: do a search Chrome user profile for files containing wrong URLs

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox on Mac:

- install sqlite (`brew install sqlite`)
- cd to Firefox profile: `cd ~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/<hash>.default-<ts>` where `<hash>` and `<ts>` are the appropriate ones for your profile
- `sqlite3 places.sqlite`
- `UPDATE urls SET url = replace(url, 'example.com', 'example2.com') WHERE url LIKE '%example.com%';`

Caveat:

- If you already have some `example2.com` history, then you will get a unique key constraint error when updating. Since I didn't care about the `example2.com` history, I deleted all those entries before running the above commands, via `DELETE from urls where url like "%example2.com%";`