# Why does chrome suggest a random Korean site in my address bar?

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

For certain URLs I visit, the address bar suggestions are returning really weird results:

> [image: Address bar suggestions]

What can cause these suggestions to show up in the address bar?  This seems to happen only when I click into certain localhost URLs.  I'm already tried to [get rid of them by SHIFT + DEL](https://superuser.com/questions/273278/how-to-remove-an-entry-from-chromes-remembered-urls-from-the-url-bar), but that doesn't work since I've never actually visited that site.

If I had to guess, they are being autopopulated from some random Google predictive text.  But why the Korean (tutorial?) site?  That site is nowhere to be seen when I actually use the URL in an actual Google search. Is this just a weird glitch in Google's predictive text, or should I be more worried about this occurring?

Here's some potentially relevant information about my setup:

- My machine is Windows 10 and running the  latest version of Chrome 63.
- I have various extensions installed (adblocker, some dev tools).
- I'm logged into my Google account, which I have active on multiple devices.
- My browser and PC are using English (US) as the language.