# How do I remove the google task bar suggestions?

Tags: google-chrome

is there a way to remove those suggestions from google? Not just the box and whisker entry, btu also the barista, the b, the sara link etc

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove an entry from Chrome's Remembered URLs from the url bar?](https://superuser.com/questions/273278/how-to-remove-an-entry-from-chromes-remembered-urls-from-the-url-bar)

Comment: I tried all the stuff u shared for some reason it doesnt work. Any combination of shift+fn+ctrl and delete doesnt help

Comment: You want to turn off search suggestions completely? See https://www.howtogeek.com/756460/how-to-disable-address-bar-search-suggestions-in-google-chrome/?

Comment: still doesnt work weird. I actually tried that before when I searched online myself.

Comment: The icons indicate the source of the auto fills. The clock icon means these are being pulled from your history. The magnifying glass means it's pulling from search suggestions. So, part of your question, at least, is the same as the duplicate. Each different source needs to be resolved separately. Start by clearing your Chrome (and possibly Google) history.